# Chrome Extension Redirect to Local Page with POST Request

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, redirect, google-chrome-extension, http-post

I am building a browser extension where I try to redirect a browser request to my page with a fair amount of data that will be contained in a JSON array returned from a service I call based on the requested URL. For example, if the user goes to example.com, I have a `chrome.webRequest.onBeforeRequest.addListener` that intercepts it based on the `urls` filter, invokes a AWS API Gateway endpoint that responds with a list of things in a JSON object. I need my local page to display that list of things in a local page.

I can show some small things by invoking the local page with URL parameters (and then treat it like a GET request), but this won't work for the amount of data i want to pass. How do I create a POST request for the `redirect` URL?

**OR, is there some other pattern I should be using to do this?**

listener code:

```
chrome.webRequest.onBeforeRequest.addListener(
    function(details) {
        if(swenToggle) {
            return { redirectUrl: chrome.extension.getURL("markup/simple.html?r=n&url=" + details.url) }; // This is fine for simple data
        } else { 
            //get the base URL 
            var baseUrl = new URL(details.url).hostname.split(".").slice(-2).join(".")
            var apiUrl = // Call AWS API here
            fetch(apiUrl).then(r => r.json()).then(result => {
                console.log('RESULT : ' + result.body); // I need to pass this body to the redirectUrl below...
            })
            return { redirectUrl: chrome.extension.getURL("markup/complex.html?sourceUrl=" + baseUrl) };
        }
    },
    { urls: "example.com"},  
    ["blocking"]
);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it with a slightly different approach. Instead of calling the AWS API from background.js, I pass the parameters needed for the API call to `complex.html` as URL params, and then invoke the AWS API in `complex.html`.